# Javascript call PHP file scandir() results

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have created a small helpdesk system which allows users to uploads files when creating tickets. The tickets are stored in a folder with an ID number that matches the ticket details that are stored in a database. Now when I open the ticket details I also want it to list the files associated with that ticket so I can open them. So far I can retrieve all the ticket details but I'm stuck with the json_encode($files) and how I can reference them with my current JavaScript code. Any ideas?

I also have the issue with the . and .. in the scandir() array and would like to remove them. When using the commented line you can see in my PHP file it makes the json_encode array look incorrect. Thanks

PHP file (snippet)

```
$value = $_POST['value'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM helpdesk WHERE ID = '$value'";
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql);

while( $rowEdit = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{               
        echo json_encode(array($rowEdit['ID'], $rowEdit['DateCreated'], $rowEdit['Name'], $rowEdit['Company'], $rowEdit['Phone'], $rowEdit['Email']));
}

$dir = 'uploads/' . $value .'/';
$files = scandir($dir);
//$files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.', '..'));
echo json_encode($files);
```

HTML file (JavaScript snippet)

```
$(function(){
    /* Opens selected ticket details  */
    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
    var output = "";
    $('#btnEdit').click(function(e){
        var value = $("#tblTickets tr.selected td:first").html();
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "sql_helpdesk_ticket_details.php",                    
                data : {value:value},
                success : function(output) {
                    var result = $.parseJSON(output);
                    $(".modal-body #txtID").val(result[0]);
                    $(".modal-body #txtDateCreated").val(result[1]);
                    $(".modal-body #txtName").val(result[2]);
                    $(".modal-body #txtCompany").val(result[3]);
                    $(".modal-body #txtPhone").val(result[4]);
                    $(".modal-body #txtEmail").val(result[5]);

                    modal.style.display = 'block';
                }
            });             
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to combine the two outputs, from what I can decipher. To do that, create one array by storing the database return in one key called `data` and the other with the files named `files` and at the end output to json:

```
define('DS',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
# Trim any spacing
$id = trim($_POST['value']);
# Just die if there are any errors
# I am presuming $_POST['value'] is numeric. If not, you need to bind_param
if(!empty($id)) {
    if(!is_numeric($id))
       die(json_encode(array('error'=>'Id not numeric')));
}
else
    die(json_encode(array('error'=>'Id can not be empty')));
# As noted, if you are allowing anything but numeric, bind_param is required
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, "SELECT * FROM `helpdesk` WHERE `ID` = '{$id}'");
$data   = array();
# Loop through and save to array
while($rowEdit = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {               
    $data['data'][] =   array(
                            $rowEdit['ID'],
                            $rowEdit['DateCreated'],
                            $rowEdit['Name'],
                            $rowEdit['Company'],
                            $rowEdit['Phone'],
                            $rowEdit['Email'])
                        );
}
# Create directory path
$dir = 'uploads'.DS.$value.DS;
# It is wise to check that it exists first
if(is_dir($dir)) {
    $files = scandir($dir);
    # I just loop through the results, but you can array_diff to filter the dots
    foreach($files as $file) {
        if(!is_file($file))
            continue;
        # Save files to array
        $data['files'][] = $file;
    }
}
# Output all the data
die(json_encode($data));
```

Your javascript will have to be adjusted to accommodate the new keys.

Comment: Thanks @Rasclatt, Now my json_encode is in the format {"data":["data1","data2"],"files":[".","..","file1","file2"]}, from JavaScript how do I reference 'data' array object 'data2' for example. 'var result = $.parseJSON(output);
$(".modal-body #txtID").val(result[data][2]);'

Comment: Sorry, I worked it out. `$(".modal-body #txtID").val(result.data[2]);`